# Swift string with key-value, is this format standard ? How can I get it as a dictionary?

Tags: swift, string, dictionary, key-value

I work with an array of string, each string var is a coded object.

I want to decode the object, when I print a string var I get something structured like that :

```
"firstName=\"Elliot\" lastName=\"Alderson\" gender=\"male\" age=\"33\",some description I also need to get"
```

Is that a standard format to store key value properties ? I can't find anything on internet. The keys are always the same so that's not a big deal to get theses values as a dictionary but I would like to know if there is like a best practice method to get theses data instead of just searching for each key and then reach value from the first quote to the second one (for each value)

Because my file is 30000 lines so I better choose the more optimized way.

Thanks !

Comment: Where does this data come from?

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica a .txt file where each line is one object to decode

Comment: And where does that text file come from?